# Where does the browser() object is defined in angluarJS ?

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

Following the Angular-phonecat tutorial, step-7 in the scenario.js a browser() and binding() objects are used but, when I tried to use them to test my application, running testacular says:

```
ReferenceError: browser is not defined
        at null.<anonymous>
```

Also Intellij Ideal says : unresolved function or method browser(). What am I missing here ?

here the code snippet from the tutorial: 
'use strict';

/* http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.e2e-testing */

```
describe('PhoneCat App', function() {

  it('should redirect index.html to index.html#/phones', function() {
    browser().navigateTo('../../app/index.html');
    expect(browser().location().url()).toBe('/phones');
  });


  describe('Phone list view', function() {

    beforeEach(function() {
      browser().navigateTo('../../app/index.html#/phones'); //<---  browser() object is not defined !!! 
    });


    it('should filter the phone list as user types into the search box', function() {
      expect(repeater('.phones li').count()).toBe(20);

      input('query').enter('nexus');
      expect(repeater('.phones li').count()).toBe(1);

      input('query').enter('motorola');
      expect(repeater('.phones li').count()).toBe(8);
    });


    it('should be possible to control phone order via the drop down select box', function() {
      input('query').enter('tablet'); //let's narrow the dataset to make the test assertions shorter

      expect(repeater('.phones li', 'Phone List').column('phone.name')).
          toEqual(["Motorola XOOM\u2122 with Wi-Fi",
                   "MOTOROLA XOOM\u2122"]);

      select('orderProp').option('Alphabetical');

      expect(repeater('.phones li', 'Phone List').column('phone.name')).
          toEqual(["MOTOROLA XOOM\u2122",
                   "Motorola XOOM\u2122 with Wi-Fi"]);
    });


    it('should render phone specific links', function() {
      input('query').enter('nexus');
      element('.phones li a').click();
      expect(browser().location().url()).toBe('/phones/nexus-s');
    });
  });


  describe('Phone detail view', function() {

    beforeEach(function() {
      browser().navigateTo('../../app/index.html#/phones/nexus-s');
    });


    it('should display placeholder page with phoneId', function() {
      expect(binding('phoneId')).toBe('nexus-s');
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: how are you running your tests? just in case e2e tests have their own config file and are run like this `testacular start testacular-e2e.conf.js`.  Here's how the conf file should look like https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/blob/master/config/testacular-e2e.conf.js

Comment: This is a very related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13173719/is-it-possible-to-mix-testacular-with-angular-scenario

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's defined within angular-scenario.js

Comment: testacular behaves very strange when I include the angular-scenario.js

Comment: Chrome 22.0: Executed 0 of 0 SUCCESS no test is executed, when I remove angular-scenario.js every goes OK ? any suggestions ?

Comment: I'd recommend seeing if you can get the [angular-seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/) project working first. You should be able to run node scripts/web-server.js & and then testacular start config/testacular-e2e.conf.js The runner.html file and the testacular-e2e.conf.js files should get you at least farther along.

Answer (score 0):

//Spec file

```
'use strict';
describe('demoApp', function() {
it('should redirect node_list.html to node_list.html#/menu', function() {
browser().navigateTo('/node_list.html');
expect(browser().location().url()).toBe('/menu');
  });

describe('menu_view', function() {
beforeEach(function() {
  browser().navigateTo('/node_list.html#/menu'); 
});
});
});

Error:
Chrome 39.0.2171 (Linux) demoApp should redirect node_list.html to node_list.html#/menu FAILED
ReferenceError: browser is not defined at Object.<anonymous> (/test/viewpage.js:5:5)
```

Comment: i am new to karma jasmine, somebody help , what is the error in this file.

Comment: If you have a new question post it on another one, do not post it as an answer