# End-to-End Testing AngularJS app with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I have an AngularJS app. I would like to implement some end-to-end testing that I can run on-demand. In an effort to do this, I've built a basic test screen with the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Test Results</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.0.0/jasmine.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.0.0/jasmine-html.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.0.0/boot.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular-mocks.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.0.0/jasmine.css" />

    <!-- Load the Test Files-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="e2e/tests.e2e.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="env.execute()">run tests</a>

</body>
</html>
```

My tests.e2e.js file looks like the following:

```
'use strict';

describe('MyApp', function() {
    browser.get('http://localhost:11000/index.html');

    describe('Welcome Screen', function () {
    });
});
```

When click "run tests" in my test runner, I get an error that says:

```
MyApp encountered a declaration exception
ReferenceError: browser is not defined
```

My question is, what am I doing wrong? The examples I've seen use browser to basically start the app. However, I can't seem to figure out how to do end-to-end tests on-demand.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where does the browser() object is defined in angluarJS ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13754336/where-does-the-browser-object-is-defined-in-angluarjs)

Comment: even after including angular-scenario.js, I still get the "browser is not defined" error.

Comment: Whats your test runner?

Comment: All of my code is posted in this question. I do not have protractor or karma setup as I thought those were more for automated testing. I want to run my tests on-demand, which is why I created the web page shown in the first code snippt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> (function (module) {
>
>     var myController = function ($scope, $http) {
>
>         $http.get("/api/myData")
>             .then(function (result) {
>                 $scope.data= result.data;
>             });
>     };
>
>     module.controller("MyController",
>         ["$scope", "$http", myController]);
>
> }(angular.module("myApp")));
>
>
>
> describe("myApp", function () {
>
>     beforeEach(module('myApp'));
>
>     describe("MyController", function () {
>
>         var scope, httpBackend;
>         beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, $httpBackend, $http) {
>             scope = $rootScope.$new();
>             httpBackend = $httpBackend;
>             httpBackend.when("GET", "/api/myData").respond([{}, {}, {}]);
>             $controller('MyController', {
>                 $scope: scope,
>                 $http: $http
>             });
>         }));
>
>         it("should have 3 row", function () {
>             httpBackend.flush();
>             expect(scope.data.length).toBe(3);
>         });
>     });
> });
> ```

Comment: Could you explain your answer please? :)