# Jasmine/Karma test: browser is not defined

Tags: testing, jasmine, karma-runner

If this test:

```
'use strict'

describe('application', function() {
    it('should login', function() {
        browser().navigateTo('/');
        expect('111').toBe('111');
    });
});
```

includes the `"browser"` line, the result is:

```
Chrome 26.0 (Windows) application should login FAILED
    ReferenceError: browser is not defined
        at null.<anonymous> (...../test/js/e2e/tests/test.js:6:9)
Chrome 26.0 (Windows): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) (0.359 secs / 0.004 secs)
```

but without this line the test succeeds.

People suggest to include `angular-scenario.js`, but this breaks tests

```
expect('111').toBe('222');
```

is evaluated as true.

What to do?

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15885079/888165

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to have your app's server running along with the karma runner. So with Node.js:

```
node app.js
```

Also, make sure you change the urlRoot property in your karma config so it doesn't conflict with your app's and yes you need angular-scenario.js

```
files = [
  ANGULAR_SCENARIO,
  ANGULAR_SCENARIO_ADAPTER,
  'test/**/*_spec.js'
];

urlRoot = '/__karma/';

proxies = {
  '/' : 'http://localhost:3000/'
};
```

Comment: The urlRoot option was one that generally isn't mentioned elsewhere and is vital.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this problem too. I believe you can only call browser() inside of a beforeEach(); Try this:

```
'use strict'

describe('application', function() {

    beforeEach(function(){
        browser().navigateTo('/');
    });

    it('should login', function() {
        expect('111').toBe('111');
    });

});
```