# End-to-End testing with Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am trying to perform some end-to-end tests of an application written with AngularJS.  Currently, I have the following tests setup in e2e.tests.js:

```
describe('MyApp', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        browser().navigateTo('../index.html');
    });

    it('should be true', function() {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

Oddly, this basic test fails. The test itself runs. However the results are:

```
203ms   browser navigate to '../index.html'
5ms expect undefined toBe true
           http://localhost:81/tests/e2e.tests.js:10:9
           expected true but was undefined
```

Considering "true" is hard-coded, I would expect it to pass this test. I have no idea how true can be undefined. What am I missing?

Comment: How you hard-coded "true" in your index.html?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13173719/is-it-possible-to-mix-testacular-karma-with-angular-scenario) should help.

Comment: Where are you getting `browser` from?

Answer (score 8):

The thing about Angular's E2E test framework is that looks like Jasmine, but it is not Jasmine. The E2E test code is actually all asynchronous, but it is written in a clever way so that the calls look normal. Most of the calls create asynchronous tasks and Future objects that are tested later. The Future object is kind of like a promise, but it's a little different. It has a `value` property that it sets when it's ready, and then it calls a `done` function to move to the next step. In E2E tests, the `expect` function takes Future objects, not values. You're seeing `undefined` because `expect` is testing against `future.value`, which in this case is `true.value`, which is undefined.

Try using one of the [available selectors that return futures](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.e2e-testing) and then test the result. Something like this:

```
expect(element("html").text()).toMatch("Our App");
```

The Future objects are not well documented, but you should be able to create a Future manually like this:

```
var trueFuture = angular.scenario.Future(
    "a true value",            // name that is displayed in the results
    function(callback) {       // "behavior" function
        callback(null, true);  // supposed to call callback with (error, result)
    });
expect(trueFuture).toEqual(true);
```

If you look in the ng-scenario source code, you can see the [place where the matcher tests `future.value` in the angular.scenario.matcher function](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/f2fab498303e00d199cb3d19a008670e214d5c10/src/ngScenario/Scenario.js#L85).

Answer (score 0):

I too have faced the similar problem and here's what I found.
You must be using ng-scenario as your framework with jasmine in config file.
The fact is that expect function in ng-scenario doesn't take any var value or Boolean value. It only takes functions like

```
expect(browser().location().path()).toContain('some/string')
```

or some other ng-scenario function like

```
expect(element('some element').html()).toContain('some String');
```

Any variable value or Boolean in expect function is undefined.

If you want to use `Boolean(true/false)` or you want your test to be passed then you have to remove 'ng-scenario' from your framework section of config file.
Try It with only jasmine!